# Javafx bind List<String> to ListView by reference

Tags: java, list, listview, javafx, reference

I am making a Javafx application and I have a `List<String>` that I update constantly and I want it to sync with a ListView I have on screen without me needing to update it manually each time. Like binding the ListView by reference. Is this possible? and if so how do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Use an [`ObservableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) instead. You can create `ObservableList`s using the factory methods in [`FXCollections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html). Remember, if you wrap your `List` in an `ObservableList` _only modify the `ObservableList`_; otherwise, the modifications won't be seen.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a basic tutorial on how List/Table/TreeView work and how to use them .. see the info tab of the javafx tag for options

Comment: @Slaw, Thank you for the answer! But when I try to bind the new ObservableList to the ListView I get an error saying `incompatible types: javafx.collections.ObservableList<java.lang.String> cannot be converted to javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue`

Comment: `ListView` has an [`items` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#itemsProperty()) that holds an `ObservableList`. You want to _set_ `items` to your `ObservableList`. The `ListView` will observe the `ObservableList` for changes.

Comment: @Slaw could you please give an example?

Comment: Simply call the setter method: `listView.setItems(yourObservableList)`.

Answer (score 5):

From your question and comments I gather you are trying to do something like:

```
ObservableList<E> list = ...;
ListView<E> view = ...;
view.itemsProperty().bind(list);
```

This will not work since `bind` expects an `ObservableValue` and `ObservableList` does not extend that interface. You don't need to bind the `items` property though. Whatever `ObservableList` is in the `items` property will be observed by the `ListView` for changes (i.e. additions, removals, permutations, and updates<sup>1</sup>). This means you should be doing something like:

```
ObservableList<E> list = ...;
ListView<E> view = ...;
view.setItems(list);
```

And then modifications to `list` will be reflected in the `ListView`.

If you *need* to bind the `items` property then your `ObservableList` will either need to be held in an implementation of `ObservableValue<ObservableList<E>>` or an [`ObservableListValue<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableListValue.html).

I recommend reading more about the basics of JavaFX; such as the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/list-view.htm#CEGGEDBF) on `ListView` or the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

---

<sup>1. An update change event is fired when a property of an element has been invalidated. In order for an `ObservableList` to observe the properties of its elements, and thus be capable of firing update events, it must be created with [`FXCollections.observableArrayList(Callback)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)).</sup>

Comment: you are a wizard =)